# Unable to retrieve similar named item from the Termstore

Tags: taxonomy, term-store

I want to get an item from TermStore. I have my string something as `Menu & Ali`. Also, in the previous iteration of my code (which is irrelevant w.r.t the query) I had added item by the using the same string i.e. `Menu ＆ Ali`. But now when I am trying to fetch it using the below snippet, I am unable to get the term.

```
Term trm = trm1.Terms.GetByName(parentName);
```

Though the term name is still the same but these are not matching ("Menu & Ali" || "Menu ＆ Ali"). On analysing this over and over again (using notepad even), I found that the two strings are no longer same. It is basically due to the `&` present in the string.

Can anyone help me / guide me the way to work this out? Is this related to the lcid (which is 1033 in this case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [TaxonomyItem.NormalizeName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.taxonomyitem.normalizename(v=office.15).aspx) method

Try changing your code to

```
Term trm = trm1.Terms.GetByName(TaxonomyItem.NormalizeName(parentName));
```

Comment: Thanks!! Though I was using CSOM approach for this, but yeah you pointed me in the right direction.